# How to save the COMPLETE figure with python-seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have produced a heatmap with seaborn, and it looks like as following in ipython notebook:
[image]

But when I tried to save it by the following way:

```
fig = plt.get_figure()
fig.savefig('heatmap.png')
```

Just part of the figure is saved and some of the labels of y-axis are lost:
[image]

Could you please tell me how to save the whole figure? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you point out which labels are lost and what parts are not printed? To me the images look the same.

Comment: @rafaelvalle Just part of the labels are shown.

Comment: Try `fig.savefig('heartmap.png',bbox_inches='tight')`

Comment: @Serenity Thanks! It works fine!!!

Comment: Got it, at the bottom!

Comment: @Serenity It may make sense to provide yur comment as an answer, which can be accepted by the questioner, such that this questions does not remain in the unsolved list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `fig.savefig('heartmap.png',bbox_inches='tight')`